# regular expressions to check length with multiple options

Tags: regex, date

I need to validate the date format, that can be either `11/11/11` or `11/22/2013`, i.e. the year block can be in `YY` or `YYYY` and the complete format will either `MM/DD/YY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`

I've this code

```
^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$
```

and I've tried

```
^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2}{4})$ // doesn't works, does nothing
```

and

```
^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2|4})$ // and it returns null every time
```

PS: I'm applying it with Javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2}|\d{4})$
```

Both `\d{2}{4}` and `\d{2|4}` are not correct regex expression. You have to do *two digits* and *for digits* separately and combine then using *or*: `(\d{2}|\d{4})`

Comment: @zzlalani Won't this validate dates like 48/66/5432 ?

Comment: @Sniffer Yes, it will. But I don't think it's part of the question here. But yes, I would **not** us that code to validate any date field in any application.

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
^\d\d?/\d\d?/\d\d(?:\d\d)?$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^\d\d?/\d\d?/\d\d(?:\d\d)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d?                      digits (0-9) (optional (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d?                      digits (0-9) (optional (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```